# In XCode, how can I view the value of variables during runtime?

Tags: c++, xcode

In other words, I have a cin>> waiting for input at parts of my program. When it stops, I want to take a look around at the variables. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Don't know XCode but I'll be utterly horrified if you can't. Keyword to search for should be something like "Watch Expression"

Comment: Wait a sec. May have nmisinterpreted you When you stop to wait for input the program is still running. You'll have to pause the debugger.

Comment: What do you mean I'll have to pause the debugger? For example somewhere in my function I will have a cin >> x. The program will wait for user input and during this time I want to look around at the environment variables. Is this possible?